# How to limit Java physical memory allocation on a cluster?

Tags: java, memory-management, cluster-computing

I'm using Java 8 on a cluster. I have submitted a test application to the cluster which just sleeps for 10 seconds. I have requested one core. The actual physical memory consumption is only 30MB but the allocated (reserved) physical memory by Java was 30GB.

Is there a way to limit the allocated physical memory? I have tried to use the -Xmx setting but this does not help. I think Java is not designed for running on a cluster.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  How is the reserved virtual memory causing an issue?  This is not the memory actually used.

Comment: Please don't use the term "memory" like this. In some places you mean RAM and in some places you mean address space and it's likely you're even confusing yourself. If you mean RAM, say "physical memory" or "RAM". If you mean virtual address space, say "virtual memory" or "address space".

Comment: What is the 'cluster' software you are using? Oracle Coherence is a pretty strong example of Java working very well in a cluster.

Comment: @beirtipol I don't know which cluster software it is because I'm just using the cluster, I'm not maintaining it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I try to solve the problem of the high amount of reserved memory. Yes, it is not the memory acutally used but it is reserved, i.e. other users of the clusters cannot use this memory.

Comment: @Erdinger a 'cluster' can mean anything. It can mean a 'Red-Hat Linux Cluster' or a 'Coherence' cluster or simply the name of a server. You need to provide more information about what exactly you are running and on what. You don't say how you are using -Xmx or how you are submitting jobs, or to what.